# Reliable External Wifi adapter for Backtrack

Tags: backtrack

Im thinking about getting this adapter for backtrack
[http://www.amazon.com/Alfa-AWUS036H-Wireless-Long-Rang-Panel/dp/B003YI4HRM/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1330456917&sr=8-3](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003YI4HRM)
Because it supports packet injection.
Do you guys recommend a better adapter and why?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Directional antennae are better than omnidirectional ones. Consider that because it really might not be true in your case.

If it is and then search ebay for TurboTenna. I have one a Danets USB-Yagi antenna and have managed 0.6 miles (open air but to an indoor WAP). It comes with a USB wifi dongle strapped to the antenna (replaceable) which shows up as:

```
148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter
```

Seems to handle injection just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have that exact bundle, and I can tell you that it works fine, and it is nice having two antennas and the suction cup-- but there are others out there. Google around for 'BackTrack usb cards' or maybe 'BackTrack wireless hcl'

You can also increase the transmit power on this unit using:

> iwpriv wlan0 highpower 1
>   iwconfig wlan0 txpower 30

Google around though, there are different USB cards out there that might better fit your needs. For example, if you are not trying to inject packets over long distances you may want something a little smaller and/or less conspicuous.

Comment: Yes I need it to be able to inject packets. And
what do you mean by conspicuous? Why would I need something smaller?

Comment: @DavidCamacho If you are pen-testing from a conference room or cafe for example, pulling out a 6 inch antenna might draw a little too much attention.. a small USB wifi stick may not.

Comment: Oh it didn't look too big on amazon probably that's why. 
Maybe it will look smaller with the 7dbi antenna and the suction cup on the back of my top cover of the laptop